# Sandbox testing for Payment Service Providers in Masterpass integration

Tags: payment-gateway, mastercard

I am working on Masterpass checkout integration for my Payment Service Provider project. I followed the Masterpass [documentation](https://developer.mastercard.com/documentation/masterpass-integration-psp) and have completed the integration.

The next step is to perform sandbox testing to make sure everything works before doing the production access request. I am unable to find any dummy merchant accounts which I can use for this. Has anyone faced this problem before?

PS: I tried creating a merchant account and tried to onboard it to my PSP but my PSP is not on the list since it doesn't have production access.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I ended up contacting Masterpass support team asking about the test merchant accounts mentioned in their documentation.  Their reply is attached below.
[image: PSP Documentation]

*Thank you for your feedback. We will update the documentation. 
As discussed in the attached email, there is no **test merchant account**. Test Merchant account can be created in MasterCard developer Portal which can be used for testing after **PSP moves into Production**.*

So I have requested Production access for my PSP.

Comment: Can you please tell me how can I get the Test merchant ID?

Answer (score 0):

You'll have to signup for a Masterpass sandbox account on [Mastercard Developer Portal](https://developer.mastercard.com/). Login with you Mastercard account, select My Projects. Click on Create Masterpass Project.
Follow the steps and your Masterpass sandbox account will be provisioned.

Comment: I have already gone through their documentation and have created sandbox account and also sandbox PSP account. The question was how to test the PSP (Payment Service Provider) integration before requesting a production access

Comment: My bad. Did you have a look at https://masterpassteststore.com/teststorefront/?sdk=java#/home. Maybe this can help you. I've integrated Masterpass with Express Checkout since we're PCI certified. We also have our PSP, so I didn't have to go through Masterpass for processing payments.